# Properties file is not available in build

Tags: spring

I have a spring project in my eclipse and I want add a properties file to it. I added the properties file at path say `abc/resources/application.properties` and the path is added in classpath. In my application context I added following bean to make properties available in source code:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:/application.properties"></property>
</bean>
```

and trying to autowire value of properties like as follows:

```
@Value("${abc.sender.email}")
private String senderEmail;
```

However, at the time I start server I am getting error saying properties file doesn't exist. I am using ant for building. Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The path location given to `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` must be absolute to the classpath. If your file is at location `abc/resources/application.properties` in the classpath. Then you have to configure it with this path: `classpath:/abc/resources/application.properties`.

If you are unsure about the path, check the binaries folder (e.g. `bin` by default from Eclipse) and give the path relative to this folder.

Also check that the problem lies not in your build and check if your WAR contains the properties file.